# iOS 'Append' Symbol/Icon

Tags: icons, ios, symbols

I am working on a calculator app for iOS. ***I would like to know what an acceptable 'Append' symbol / Icon would be*** - would it be a downward pointing arrow? A curved arrow?

Anything helps,

Erway Software

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid that icon request topics are of topic for this site, as outlined in our [FAQ].

Comment: @JonW Where could I ask it?

Comment: @Erway, the question has some merit in my opinion. It's best to rephrase the question to request examples of the symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try an I beam cursor with a curved downward arrow ... and maybe an underscore.  This would work for an append/prepend.